# How to apply custom font to navigation drawer items in xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am working on xamarin android. For all the `TextView` and `EditText` boxes, I am able to set custom font. But I am not getting how to set font to navigation drawer items as we set the text from `menu.xml` file.

My code:

```
var fontSemibold = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Context.Assets, "fonts/MyProject-App-Semibold.ttf");
btn_first.Typeface = fontSemibold;
btn_second.Typeface = fontSemibold;
```

Can anybody tell me, is there a way to set custom font to navigation drawer items? Will be really thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to you style.xml file

```
 <style name="RobotoMenuViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
      <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/sans-serif-smallcaps</item>
 </style>
```

Add this style to navigation drawer      `app:itemTextAppearance="@style/RobotoMenuViewStyle"`

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
 android:id="@+id/navigation_menu"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 app:itemTextAppearance="@style/RobotoMenuViewStyle"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
 app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_menu_header"
 app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer" />
```

Comment: Hi Thank you, i have given the style..but it is saying no resource found @fonts like that...can you tell me what to do

Comment: i kept my fonts folder in assets folder and then acceszsing it...but it is displaying no resource found...please help e

Comment: Have you added the font within the asset folder's Font folder ?

Comment: Is the build action of the font properties set to android asset ?